# Binomial-like sum involving falling factorials

Tags: binomial-coefficients, summation, pochhammer-symbol

We know that $\sum_{k=0}^n a^k \frac{n^{\underline k}}{k!} = (1+a)^n$. Is there a known (preferably closed) form for $\sum_{k=0}^n a^k n^{\underline k}$?

Comment: My copy of Mathematica gives $e^{1/a} a^n \Gamma (n+1,\frac{1}{a})$, where $\Gamma(s, x)$ is the [Upper Incomplete Gamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function). Do you consider that closed form?

Comment: maple gave hypergeom$([1,-n],[],-a)$ where the $[1,-n]$ are apparently "numerators" and the empty $[]$ means no "denominators". I'm not familiar with that, but it may be just a re-write of your sum.

Comment: Twice you wrote and I don't know: what does $\,n^{\underline k}\;$ mean?

Comment: @DonAntonio it means $n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots (n-k+1)$.

Comment: Well I'll be...! I had no idea. Thanks @Ted

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435780/binomial-like-sum