# Binomial-like Sum

Tags: binomial-coefficients

We know that $\sum_{k=0}^n a^k \frac{n^{\underline k}}{k!} = (1+a)^n$. Is there a known (preferably closed) form for $\sum_{k=0}^n a^k/k!$ ?

This question was prompted by [another recent question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433313/binomial-like-sum-involving-falling-factorials)

Comment: Letting $n\to \infty$ yields:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{a^k}{k!} = e^a
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be written in terms of the incomplete Gamma function: $\dfrac{e^a}{n!} \Gamma(n+1,a)$.